# Python 2.7.5 IDLE GUI wont open

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle, turtle-graphics

I have been having a problem with Python lately, I closed a .py file while working with Python Turtle in V2.7.5 of Python and ever since I can't open the Python IDLE. I've tried everything I can think of... Un-installing and re-installing, opening it from inside the idlelib and I just can't get it right so can someone please explain what's going on because I've tried everything.

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

Instead of using Python's IDLE im using notepad++ and it works fine

Comment: What happens when you try to launch IDLE? Does it give any error, does it freeze, does it say some library is not found, etc? What variety of machine are you on? PC/Mac/Linux/...

Comment: can you just run python from the command prompt in the terminal window?

Comment: No i tried to run it from the CMD and it wouldn't start. Im running windows 7 64bit and all it does is freeze no error message, nothing.

Comment: Maybe you should try installing python3 & see if it has similar problem?!

Comment: I found a different fix for it, I keep python 2.7 installed and just use notepad ++ and the place to write my code, its not as nice but it works

Comment: Please take a look at the "Related" questions. You might actually solve the main problem.